# ¿Cómo puedo leer determinadas líneas en python?

Tags: python

Mi idea es poder cargar archivos .txt
pero desconozco la cantidad de líneas que contiene.
Mi idea es ser capaz de leer todas las líneas una a una y almacenarlas en variables.
En caso de tener 100 líneas que almacene una por una en variables, para más tarde poder acceder a ellas.
Sé como abrir el .txt, lo he hecho de la siguiente manera.

```
if x == '1':
  archivo = input("Introduce el nombre del .txt= ")
  f = open(archivo)
  texto = f.readlines()
```

Comment: ¿Para que quieres cada linea en variables? Lo que planteas es generalmente una mala idea,  Indiza sobre la lista directamente retornada por readlines...

Comment: @FJSevilla es porque cada línea debe ser un uduario, entonces deben estar separadas, no?

Comment: No tiene porque, `texto[0]` es un usuario, `texto[1]` el siguiente, y así sucesivamene... Lo normal es usar un contenedor, sea una lista, un diccionario, etc. Esto te facilita la modificación de los datos y la posible contruccion del nuevo txt con ellos modificados. Puedes parsear los datos de cada linea antes de pasarlos a la lista para que contenga cada dato del usuario por separado, por ejemplo `[{"nombre": "fulanito", "edad": 27}, {"nombre": "menganito", "edad": 30}, ...]` pero para eso neceitaria saber la estructura del fichero, si usas clases (POO) para representar  cada usuario, etc

Comment: @FJSevilla no, no uso POO, entonces, como lo haría? Los usuarios simplemente es el nombre, tal que así.
Fulanito
Menganito

Comment: Si cada nombre está en una fila, entonces como comento arriba basta con que uses tu lista `texto`, cada item es un usuario ¿O tu idea inicial era usar el nombre del usuario como nombre de la variable? ¿Si es así que valor tendria cada variable?

Comment: No, mi idea es poner por ejemplo usuario1 como variable

Answer (score 0):

Como te recomiendan en comentarios, puedes usar una lista, es un tipo muy útil debido a que no necesitas fijarle un tamaño y lo lees de la misma forma que lees a un arreglo.

```
f = open("archivo.txt")
l = []   # la nueva lista

for line in f:
    l.append(line[:-1]) # [:-1] eliminará la secuencia de escape \n que se
                        # genera en cada línea

f.close()

print(l) # solo con fines de prueba, así verás si el resultado te convence
```

Luego podrás hacer uso de X usuario en el resto de tu programa accediendo a la lista.

Comment: Perfecto, me lo deja en una lista, ahora en caso de que quiera sacar todos en variables, pero sin saber el número de usuarios que tengo, como lo haría?

Comment: Tienes las funciones de la lista, como length, esa te dará el tamaño que tiene, pero a que te refieres con sacarlos en variables?

Comment: me refiero a que me gustaría poner usuario1 = 'fulanito' y así constantemente. Pero no se cuantos usuarios tendrán los ficheros.

Comment: Bueno, no creo que sea necesario desperdiciar memoria en más variables, en lugar de usuario1 = 'fulanito', usuario2 = 'menganito' con la lista tendrías usuario[0] = 'fulanito', usuario[1] = 'menganito'.... (hasta los que existieran en los archivos, míralo como una forma de tener varias variables en una sola) al ser una lista no necesitas ponerle un límite pues esta crece a medida que le insertas valores, como te dije, la función len: **len(lista)** te devolverá cuantos elementos tiene la lista (la misma cantidad de líneas que hay en el archivo) de esa forma sabrás cuantos usuarios tienes